# スワップファイルを利用した Composer のインストールができない

Tags: php, centos, shellscript, composer

AWS EC2 において、Auto Scaling で自動作成された CentOS のインスタンスをシェルスクリプトで初期化しようとしています。

その場合、普通に Composer をインストールしようとするとメモリ不足でエラーが発生してしまいます。
スワップファイルを作成して対応できると聞き、以下のように書きました

```
# Generate a swap file for composer
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1

# Install composer
cd /var/www/html
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
php composer.phar install
```

しかし、作成されたインスタンスを確認すると、Composer のインストールができていないことが分かりました。
スワップファイルが作成されるところまではできているので、Composer をインストールする段階でコケているのは分かっています。

どうコケているのか確かめるために、素の CentOS インスタンスを立ち上げ、シェルスクリプトの中身を順にコピペして実行したのですが、この方法だと正常にインストールできてしまいました。

シェルスクリプトで初期化した時だけ失敗するのは、どのような原因が考えられますか？

Answer (score 0):

PHPにパスは通っていますか？

```
echo "ここまで進んだ" > logfile
```

みたいな行を入れて、どこまで進んでいるか確認してみるのもいいかも知りません。
コマンドの出力や戻り値も入れると原因究明し易くなるかと思います。